# Ansible Tower: How to pass job number into playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-tower

I have written an Ansible playbook that needs as one of its parameters the job number that is running it so that I make add a reference to the job to a database that I maintain. How can I get the Tower template to pass this to the playbook?

Here is my current solution which is not ideal:

I first kick off the template which contains my playbook using `tower-cli` at which point the job number is returned to me. I then pass the job number as a parameter to another template which calls a playbook that writes the job number to the database.

Ideally I want to be able to run a single playbook via `tower-cli` and not worry about the job number when doing so. I would like Tower to pass the job number to the original playbook so as not to require a second playbook. Any other solutions to this problem would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what 'Job number' means. But, assuming you mean 'Job ID', 
Tower automatically adds the variables to job environment, you can get tower job id by using {{ tower_job_id }} anywhere in the playbook.

You also have access to various other variables set by tower, refer to following documentation.

[Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html)